# Can I get additional reputation reward from badge like nice question or nice answers?

Tags: discussion

We have the badge system that encourage users use more features on the site. Does that make sense to give user more reputations after achieving badges like nice questions or nice answers?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're saying. Which badges in particular are you referring to? Are you suggesting adding a reputation bonus to some badges, or are you suggesting that with certain badges (like Good Question and Good Answer, for example) since the poster has already gained reputation for that answer or question that a badge as well is unnecessary?

Comment: The latter. Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more specific and/or explicit, please?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, I am new to CV and have a lot of questions in mind. When I ask this question I did not thing though.

Comment: While there's not much issue with discussing these things, note that changes to the system would be network wide, so if your intent is to propose some change this would probably be better placed on the network meta (meta.stackexchange.com). If that's what you're trying to achieve, once your question is polished up it would be possible to migrate it. (Though I expect this has probably already been raised there, so check for duplicates first.)

Comment: Your title still seems to be asking the former (it appears to be a request for additional reputation for earning a badge) rather than the latter (questioning whether both badges and reputation are necessary)

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I think myself is not clear what is the question, but your answers explains my confusion 100% in detail in both ways. If you think it is necessary to make it more clear, please feel free to edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reputation and badges are not simply rewards (and indeed, as rewards they're  fairly flimsy when one can earn very real rewards putting the same effort into other activities).

Instead, reputation and badges also (and perhaps more usefully) serve as signals to others, but they signal different things.

At the present time I have a similar reputation to whuber (and I hope he will excuse me mentioning him in my answer), but he has a substantially higher number of "Good Answer" badges than I do (about 5 for every 3 I have, even though I have answered more questions). Good Answer badges are quite rare, so someone holding a lot of them tells you something important about the standard of their answers.

More of the story comes when you look at the tag badges, for example, whuber has a `spatial` tag badge, spatial statistics being a topic on which he has vastly more knowledge than me. Knowing that he has that tag badge and I don't might help to indicate his relative expertise on the topic.

There are some users on site that have a large amount of reputation that has been mainly gained from asking good questions. That certainly indicates important contributions to the site, but might give you a different view of their answer to some question when compared to a user of similar reputation which has been almost entirely earned on good answers.

Reputation tells our readers only part of the story. Badges tell another part. Both can be useful in giving users a picture of the likely value of what is being said (if it's not otherwise clear). It's no guarantee of course -- anybody might have an off day and give an answer below their usual standard, for example, and ultimately an answer must stand on its own merits -- but such indications can sometimes be useful.